# Find Array Elements in Array using JPA Query in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to find to array elements in array, but getting error

```
@Query(
   "SELECT i FROM User i WHERE (i.personalDetail.gender = :gender) and " +
       "(:country is null or i.contactDetail.country = :country) and " +
       "(COALESCE(:state, NULL) is null or i.contactDetail.state IN (:state)) and " +
       "(COALESCE(:motherLanguage, NULL) is null or i.personalDetail.motherLanguage IN (:motherLanguage))"
    )
    Page<User> findAllUser(
            @Param("gender") Optional<String> gender,
            @Param("country") Optional<String> country,
            @Param("state") Optional<List<String>> state,
            @Param("motherLanguage") Optional<List<String>> motherLanguage,
            Pageable pageable
    );
```

```
 @RequestParam("country") Optional<String> country,
 @RequestParam("state") Optional<String[]> state,
 @RequestParam("motherLanguage") Optional<String[]> motherLanguage,



Page<User> pageObj = userRepository.findAllUser(
                gender,
                country,
                Optional.of(Arrays.asList(state.orElse(new String[] { }))),                Optional.of(Arrays.asList(motherLanguage.orElse(new String[] { }))),
                pageable
        );
```

```
Model

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Type(type = "string-array")
    @Column(
            name = "mother_language",
            columnDefinition = "text[]"
    )
    private String[] motherLanguage;
```

I found that the error is due to this line in Query

```
"(COALESCE(:motherLanguage, NULL) is null or i.personalDetail.motherLanguage IN (:motherLanguage))"
```

My query properly properly works for `state` parameter because state is just a string, but  `motherLanguage`is an array.

Basically i want to know how i can query in array using array. If found something on internet `SELECT ARRAY[1,2] && ARRAY[1,3,4,7];` but when i tried to put `&&` in JPA Query it is giving error

```
"(COALESCE(:motherLanguage, NULL) is null or i.personalDetail.motherLanguage && (:motherLanguage))"
```

This is the ERROR For Bellow Query

```
"(:motherLanguage is null or i.personalDetail.motherLanguage IN :motherLanguage) and " +
```

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Parameter value element [Hindi] did not match expected type [[Ljava.lang.String; (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [Hindi] did not match expected type [[Ljava.lang.String; (n/a)]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [Hindi] did not match expected type [[Ljava.lang.String; (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [Hindi] did not match expected type [[Ljava.lang.String; (n/a)]
```

Comment: Don't use optionals...bind plain lists instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the JPQL query as this:

```java
@Query(
    "SELECT i FROM User OR WHERE (i.personalDetail.gender = :gender) AND " +
    "(:country IS NULL OR i.contactDetail.country = :country) AND " +
    "(:state IS NULL OR i.contactDetail.state IN :state) AND " +
    "(:motherLanguage IS NULL OR i.personalDetail.motherLanguage IN :motherLanguage)"
)
```

JPA should be smart enough to compare a bound collection directly against null.  There is no need to use `COALESCE()` as you were using it.

Comment: Not working, I have posted the error in Post

Comment: Don't use optionals...use regular (nullable lists).

Comment: Still Not working `String[] motherLanguage1 = new String[] {"Hindi"};  `       >>>>. Passing as  >>>>> `Arrays.asList(motherLanguage1),` Same above error, I have removed optional

Answer (score 0):

Try with two parameters :

```
(:motherLanguageB IS NULL OR i.personalDetail.motherLanguage IN :motherLanguage)
```

Force to null if list is empty :

```
if(motherLanguages != null && motherLanguages.isEmpty()) motherLanguages = null;
```

And set the parameters (don't know how to this with Spring Data):

```
 setParameter("motherLanguageB", motherLanguages == null ? null : 1)
.setParameter("motherLanguage", motherLanguages);
```